# How do I determine which volumes are used by an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Can this be done in a simple manner using the management console alone?

My current approach is to go through each volume and check the "attachment information". But it's quite a tedious approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually check it from the ec2 instance informations, as described in the [ec2 user guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-describing-volumes.html)

> 1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
> 2. In the navigation pane, choose Instances.
> 3. To view more information about an instance, select it.
> 4. In the details pane, you can inspect the information provided about root and block devices.

[image: example]